# Why does enabling intarray extension on PostgreSQL cause 10x performance degradation?

Tags: postgresql

Here's a log of what I run.
With intarray off, it runs in 56ms.
I then enable intarray, and run the same query, and it's much slower.

Do I need to reindex the table, or something like that after enabling the extension?

```
test_int=# explain analyze select * from tutor_topic tt1 where tt1.topic_id @> '{5,7,8,9}';
                                                      QUERY PLAN                                                       
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on tutor_topic tt1  (cost=0.00..29742.00 rows=1000 width=105) (actual time=24.903..1937.480 rows=68 loops=1)
   Filter: (topic_id @> '{5,7,8,9}'::integer[])
   Rows Removed by Filter: 999932
 Planning time: 0.084 ms
 Execution time: 1937.521 ms
(5 rows)

Time: 1938.000 ms
test_int=# DROP EXTENSION intarray;                                                                                                                              DROP EXTENSION
Time: 10.516 ms
test_int=# explain analyze select * from tutor_topic tt1 where tt1.topic_id @> '{5,7,8,9}';
                                                            QUERY PLAN                                                            
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on tutor_topic tt1  (cost=108.78..487.18 rows=100 width=105) (actual time=55.063..55.138 rows=68 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (topic_id @> '{5,7,8,9}'::integer[])
   Heap Blocks: exact=68
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on message_rdtree_idx  (cost=0.00..108.75 rows=100 width=0) (actual time=55.047..55.047 rows=68 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (topic_id @> '{5,7,8,9}'::integer[])
 Planning time: 0.196 ms
 Execution time: 55.180 ms
(7 rows)

Time: 56.095 ms
test_int=#
```

This is the schema for the tutor_topic table;

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tutor_topic                                               
(                                                                                    
      tutor_id              INT NOT NULL,                                            
      topic_id              INT[]                                                    
);
```

These are the indices:

```
ALTER TABLE tutor_topic ADD FOREIGN KEY (tutor_id) REFERENCES tutor(tutor_id);       
CREATE INDEX ON tutor_topic (tutor_id);                                              
CREATE INDEX message_rdtree_idx ON tutor_topic USING GIN (topic_id)   

 Schema |           Name            | Type  | Owner  |    Table    
--------+---------------------------+-------+--------+-------------
 public | message_rdtree_idx        | index | xxxxxx | tutor_topic
 public | topic_pkey                | index | xxxxxx | topic
 public | tutor_pkey                | index | xxxxxx | tutor
 public | tutor_topic_tutor_id_idx  | index | xxxxxx | tutor_topic
 public | tutor_topic_tutor_id_idx1 | index | xxxxxx | tutor_topic
```

Answer (score 3):

I figured out the answer!

When creating the index, I need to specify the function from the extension:
CREATE INDEX message_rdtree_idx ON tutor_topic USING GIN (topic_id gin__int_ops);

Now performance matches. From the explain analyze call, it appears it was not using the index at all.